# How to get the CID of a folder?

Tags: ipfs

The closest and only answer I saw is: `ipfs add -r {folder-name}`

But it adds the whole folder to IPFS (but you don't want to really add, but simply to get its CID) and displays all CIDs from all files.

A better command I came with is `ipfs add -qr --only-hash {folder-name}`, because it only gets the CID instead of adding all the files; but, still, it outputs all CIDs instead of only the folder's CID you want.

Answer (score 2):

## Working answer

How to display the CID of a folder:
`ipfs add -qr --only-hash {folder-name} | tail -n 1`

Display base32/CID v2 of a folder:
`ipfs add -qr --only-hash {folder-name} | tail -n 1 | ipfs cid base32`

### Updated answer by @Jorropo

How to display the CID of a folder:
`ipfs add -Qr --only-hash {folder-name}`

Display base32/CID v2 of a folder:
`ipfs add -Qr --only-hash {folder-name} | ipfs cid base32`

### Bonus

Display the CID of a single file:
`ipfs add -q --only-hash {file-name}`

Display the base32/CID v2 of a single file:
`ipfs add -q --only-hash {file-name} | ipfs cid base32`